# node js ffmpeg complexfilter overlay another video

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, overlay

I have this code planning to output a video containing vid1 and vid2 side by side. So I add a padding to the right of vid1 and tried to use overlay to put vid2 on that space but instead the output video shows a duplicate of vid1 to the right. Can someone please tell me what is wrong with my code and how to fix it? Thanks

```
ffmpeg("vid1.mp4")
.input("vid2.mp4")
.complexFilter([
    "scale=300:300[rescaled]",
    {
        filter:"pad",options:{w:"600",h:"300"},
        inputs:"rescaled",outputs:"padded"
    },
    {
        filter:"overlay", options:{x:"300",y:"0"},
        inputs:["padded","vid2.mp4"],outputs:"output"
    }
], 'output')
.output("output.mp4")
.on("error",function(er){
    console.log("error occured: "+er.message);
})
.on("end",function(){
    console.log("success");
})
.run();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used following code in a previous project to do the same thing:

```
ffmpeg()
.input("vid1.mp4")
.input("vid2.mp4")
.complexFilter([
  '[0:v]scale=300:300[0scaled]',
  '[1:v]scale=300:300[1scaled]',
  '[0scaled]pad=600:300[0padded]',
  '[0padded][1scaled]overlay=shortest=1:x=300[output]'
])
.outputOptions([
  '-map [output]'
])
.output("output.mp4")
.on("error",function(er){
  console.log("error occured: "+er.message);
})
.on("end",function(){
  console.log("success");
})
.run();
```

Note that in this case, any audio from the video is disregarded and dropped. If you want audio as well, you will have to add complex mixdown filters that use the [0:a] and [1:a] channels as input.

The -map parameter in the outputOptions list tells the ffmpeg project to map the variable output into the output.mp4 file. If you need audio, you will have to add another -map parameter to the outputOptions as well for the audio.

Comment: Success! Thank you!